# Connect to EC2 Instance - Bitnami/Django

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, bitnami, amazon-ami

Im super new to Amazon Cloud, nevermind ec2, I'm following the [amazon documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html), which states:

1. In a command line shell, `change directories to the location of the private key file` that you created when you launched the instance.

   Use the chmod command to make sure your private key file isn't publicly viewable. For example, if the name of your private key file is my-key-pair.pem, you would use the following command:
2. `chmod 400 my-key-pair.pem`
3. `ssh -i my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

I'm using

```
ssh -i myvaluepair.pem bitnami@<instancehere>.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

I fail on step #3 with an error of:

```
ssh: connect to host <instancehere>.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

I've tried rebooting the AMI too - any thoughts? I'm simply trying to connect to bitnami on my amazon ec2 instance.

I have the follow security policy:
[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with:
[image: img]

It should have been:

```
22 (SSH)        0.0.0.0/0
80 (HTTP)       0.0.0.0/0
```

and **not sg-e925a882**

I was [using this link](http://bitnami.com/tutorials/amazon_machine_images) to properly setup a bitnami-djangostack-1.5.1. instance.

Comment: You want to be careful about opening port 22 up to everyone. If possible, you should lock it down to just the ips you use.